# помогите разобраться в юнит тестах

Tags: юнит-тесты

есть приложение, которое периодически запускает обработку:

- забирает данные из базы
- фильтрует их
- обрабатывает
- распределяет полученные результаты по нескольким таблицам

проект развивается и меняются как данные так и их структура, а также принципы обработки

хотелось иметь юнит-тесты для поддержки этого функционала

помогите правильно спроектировать тесты, что и как можно протестировать в этом приложении?

а что имеет смысл оставить как есть?

проблема в том, что сейчас все компактно, но в тоже время монолитно и не тестируемо

если же деструктуризировать продукт, будет тяжелее видеть весь код сразу

Comment: юнит тесты не должны зависеть от другого функционала продукта.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, получается в рамках описанной задачи можно протестировать только `алгоритмы обработки` ? и только на тестовых данных?

Comment: юнит тесты проверяют корректность работы отдельных модулей. вы путаете с интеграционными тестами, которые должны проверить функционал ПО, взаимодействие компонентов

Comment: Юнит-тесты предназначены для тестирования единицы кода. Чаще всего юнит-тесты пишут для каждого метода тестируемого класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unit тест** проверяет маленькую часть системы - одну функцию, один метод, одно сообщение.

**Unit тест** всегда работает в изоляции - все зависимости заменяются на на заглушки (stub и mock).

Если в вашем приложение совсем нет тестов и функционал описан недостаточно четко, то вы можете начать с создания **Характеризационных тестов ([Characterization test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test))**. Эти тест описывают поведение всей системы или ее части. Не стоит создавать большое количество подобных тестов, так как они сложно поддерживаемые и "хрупкие".

Comment: Дайте ссылку на описание `Характеризационных тестов`. В гугле не нашел подобного словосочетания.

Comment: добавил ссылку в ответ